# syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php

hi im new to php and i have this error i don't know what is the cause and i tried to solve it but no luck ..
  here is the error

```
syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\co\admin\modules\common\lib\classes\modules.php on line 169
```

here is my code

```
                foreach ( $parts as $part )
                {
169=>               $value = explode( "=", $part )[1];
                    $key = explode( "=", $part )[0];
                    if ( !$key )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $temp[$key] = $value;
                }
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5):

PHP can only subscript array elements from a variable, not from a returned value on the stack.

You need an intermediate variable or use this construct which looks like what you need...

```
list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part);
```

Now `$key` and `$value` will have the values you require. It's also shorter and nice to read :)

Comment: list is a good idea, +1!

Comment: Nice brief version. I like it!

Answer (score 4):

PHP does not allow this syntax. You have to store the value from explode, then choose which part you want :

```
$value = explode("=", $part);
$value = $value[1];
// etc
```

Comment: For those landing here from google: This syntax **is** supported as of php version 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the return value of explode() function as an array immediately. You should store it in a variable:

```
$value = explode("=", $part);
$value = $value[1];
```

Though, this feature will be introduced in PHP 6.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
$set = explode( "=", $part );
$key = $set[0];
$value = $set[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $parts as $part )
{
  $array = explode( "=", $part );
  $key = [0];
  $value = $values[1];
  if ( $key )
  {
     $temp[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

You have to split it up  ... and get rid of the continue ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the indexer immediately after the explode function. Try something like this:

```
$array = explode("=", $part);
$value = $array[1];
```